# How can I databind to a static CLR property?

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I want to databind a textblock to some CLR objects so I can display details about a users system.

Example:

```
TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=System.Environment.OSVersion}"
```

How can I pull this type of thing off?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your only problem is that `System.Environment.OSVersion` is `static`.

This should work:

```
<UserControl 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    ...
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={x:Static sys:Environment.OSVersion}}">
</UserControl>
```